# Migrate Delphi 5 project to using SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, delphi, sql-server-2008

I'm migrating an old delphi 5 process from SQL Server 7 to SQL Server 2008.

One TQuery component not find all the fields of a table. Using "Add all fields" I only get 5 of 25 fields.

Any idea of how can I get all the fields?

Comment: I'm using a TDatabase that connect to the sql using a Alias name. Then in the TQuery i specified DataBasename the name of the TDatabase.(I'm not sure what is DBE, i'm using the graphic interface to connect for the data base.)

Comment: Not sure what BDE is! You are going to need to understand what mechanism you use to connect your Delphi code and the database. BDE is most likely for D5 since, dbExpress wasn't released until D6.

Comment: If you're using BDE still, I would highly recommend you port over to ADO.  (So use TADOConnection rather than TDatabase, and TADOQuery rather than TQuery etc.)

Answer (score 3):

If you're still using `TQuery`, you're using the `BDE` (Borland Database Engine). There have been dozens of changes to `SQL Server` since D5 was released, including Unicode support and lots of datatypes being added. It's highly unlikely that you'll be able to simply convert.

If you're using a higher version (SKU) than Professional, you should have `ADO` components, and can possibly replace the `BDE` with them. D5 Professional didn't include the `ADO` components; they were sold separately (and fairly expensive, considering the cost of the D5 Pro upgrade from D4) and probably are no longer available. You might be able to still find third-party ADO components that will support D5 and `SQL Server 2008`, though. Good luck!